# Is it possible to put a combo box (drop down list) in a MS Access MsgBox?

Tags: ms-access, combobox, drop-down-menu, msgbox

There is a combo box (dropdown list) with a list of revenue types. If the user types into the box a value that is not part of the list, a msgBox pops up and asks them if they want to add that value to the list.

Here is my problem: In that msg box, I want to give the user a combo box list of revenue groups to choose from (so that the essence of the dialog is "oh, you want to add a new revenue type. Now pick which revenue group it's from).

Is there any way to add a combo box to a msgBox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is not. The usual solution is to build a small form and use that as a dialog.

```
 DoCmd.OpenForm "TheCustomFormName",acNormal,,,,acDialog
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try out Arvin Meyer's MsgBox replacement form:

http://www.datastrat.com/Download/MsgBox2K.zip

I've never used it, but Arvin's an Access guru of long standing.

For what it's worth, what you describe is a dialog, not a message box, so in that case, I'd design a custom dialog form.

Dmitri Furman also has a MsgBox replacement:

http://iridule.net/cu/files/mboxfunction.zip

...but his sounds like a more straightforward replacement, and likely not helpful for your situation. I include the link just for completeness.